# Assigning two variables in a Perl foreach loop

Tags: perl, foreach

is it possible to somehow assign 2 variables and 2 arrays to a foreach loop ? This is my code

```
ARRAYS:

$self->{types} = [qw(DIA UPD UP2 BGD ENQ)];
$self->{status} = [qw(Waiting Running Stopped Shutdown Reserviert)];
```

---

```
sub check{
  my $self = shift;
  if ($self->mode =~ /netweaver::processes::list/) {
    $self->SUPER::check();
    $self->add_ok("všetko ok");
  } elsif ($self->mode =~ /netweaver::processes::count/) {
    foreach my $status (@{$self->{status}}) {
      $self->{num_status}->{$status} = 0 if !exists $self->{num_status}->{$status};

      my $metric = lc 'num_' . $status;
      $self->set_thresholds(metric => $metric,
        warning                  => '5', critical => '20',
      );
      $self->add_message(
        $self->check_thresholds(metric => $metric, value => $self->{num_status}->{$status}),
        sprintf "%d %s process%s", $self->{num_status}->{$status}, $status, $self->{num_status}->{$status} == 1 ? "" : "es");
      $self->add_perfdata(
        label => $metric, value => $self->{num_status}->{$status},
      );
    }

  } else {
    if (! @{$self->{workprocs}}) {
      $self->add_unknown("no workprocs were found");
    }
  }
}
```

and I need to print data from types array above...exactly as I did in sprint before

> ```
> $self->{num_status}->{$status}, $status
> ```

something like `$self->{num_types}->{$types}, $types`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've cleaned up the indentation in your code. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever find yourself having to walk across two arrays simultaneously, then it's worth asking whether you can combine the two arrays into one.

```
$self->{data} = [{
  type   => 'DIA',
  status => 'Waiting',
}, {
  type   => 'UPD',
  status => 'Running',
}, {
  # etc
}];
```

Then you can walk them like this:

```
foreach my $data (@{ $self->{data} }) {
  my $type   = $data->{type};
  my $status = $data->{status};
  ...
}
```

But if you don't want to change your existing data structures, then you need to iterate across the array indexes, rather than the array elements.

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#{ $self->{status} }) {
  my $status = $self->{status}[$i];
  my $type   = $self->{type}[$i];
  ...
}
```

The problem, of course, comes when the two arrays get out of step and one has more elements than the other.